# Debugging. Step into android source code. Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I want to debug an android application, and I want to step into Android source codes. I've already attached android source inside my application. Whenever I try to step inside android source code. It shows the pointer on wrong line. The image is attached[image]

Comment: I've had something similar happen to me in Netbeans. I ended up copying the contents of the file to a new file, deleting the old file, and renaming the new file to the old file. I wish I could point you to a specific answer, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project in IDE?